# Returning std::initializer_list in clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++

Consider this sample of code:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(auto e: []()->std::initializer_list<int>{return{1,2,3};}())
        std::cout<<e<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it with g++ (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10))
and the output is correct.
In clang++ (Debian clang version 3.5.0-9 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)) output for example:

```
0
2125673120
32546
```

Where first line are always 0 and last two are *"random"*.

It's error in clang or something else? I think that this sample of code is correct.

**Update:**

When the lambda function return type is something else (e.g. std::vector or std::array) this code works fine.

Comment: accepting the duplicate recommendation: the code here is functionally identical to the example at the bottom of the linked question  (range-based for loop binds as `auto && __begin = `)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C++11 8.5.4 List Initialization [dcl.init.list]:

> 5 An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated an array of `N` elements of type `E`, where `N` is the number of elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array. If a narrowing conversion is required to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed.
>
> 6 The lifetime of the array is the same as that of the `initializer_list` object.

The `return` statement of your lambda initializes a temporary `std::initializer_list<int>` and returns a copy thereof. This is all good, except that the lifetime of the array to which it refers ends at the end of the full-expression. Accessing the dead array through the `initializer_list` outside of the lambda results in undefined behavior.

An `initializer_list` isn't a container, it's a reference to a temporary container. If you try to use it like a container you're going to have a bad time.

In C++14 (quoting N4140) paragraph 6 was clarified to:

> 6 The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object (12.2), except that initializing an `initializer_list` object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary.

by the resolution of [CWG issue 1290](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1290). This clarification makes it impossible to use an `initializer_list` as, e.g., a member variable which was the intention of C++11. Even in C++14, however, your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: ... but the specification of range-based for loops defines the `initializer_list` object to be assigned to a variable with (deduced) rvalue reference type: `auto && __range = range-init;` and the temporaries lifetime is thus extended, isn't it? No copy of the temporary is returned, the temporary itself is returned: It is the temporary return value of that lambda that the reference is bound to. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Columbo The underlying array should be destroyed before the lambda returns.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, the underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of the original initialiser list object has ended. Therefore, your code may exhibit undefined behaviour. Switch to C++14.

Comment: I tried to compile with flags: -std=c++11 and -std=c++14. Same behavoiur.

Comment: @MichałSzczepaniak then you are probably using an old standard library implementation (which is likely since you're on Debian).

Comment: Could you provide some reference text to support this?

Comment: @chris http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: @райтфолд Clang and GCC use same header files. Where is difference?

Comment: C++14 does not define behavior for this program any more so than C++11.